# On appear Modifier wont trigger listener on first view appearance after Initial sign in to app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

On appear Modifier wont trigger listener on first view appearance.
When I sign into the application and click the appropriate tab view it does not trigger the on appear... it only triggers it when I click it twice...It works in all other situations but when I sign in for the first time it does not trigger when I click the Conversationlistview Tab.

```
ContentView {
        TabView {
           View()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Friends", systemImage: "message")
                }
                .tag(Tab.friends)
               
            View()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Messages", systemImage: "person.fill")
                }
                .tag(Tab.Messages)
                .onAppear {
                  setupInitialListeners()
                }
           
          
        
        View()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
            }
            .tag(Tab.settings)
            
         


       }

}
......
struct ConversationsListView: View {

var body: some View {
                  Vstack{
  //OTHER CONTENT TO DISPLAY HERE
                        }
                        .onAppear(perform: {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                
                                setupInitialListeners()
                            }
                            
                        })
}
}.....
```

I have tried placing the setupInitialListener in a ViewModel then calling it as ViewModel.setupInitialListener. I placed the on appear on the tabview. I placed it in the sign in function when I sign in to the app initially. I tried calling it from the @main Delegate. I also created a custom tab format with navigation links. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: You need to declare `struct ContentView: View {...}` and have a `var body: some View {...}`
 in it, where you have your `TabView`.

Comment: I do have a body of course. I dont think the app would run without it. Thanks tho.

Comment: show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did above... i have a tab view and an on appear in another view that im navigating to after clicking the tab... thats really all there is to it.. it works but it wont work the first time after i sign in... the sign in method isnt related to this issue... ive skipped the sign in process entirely and it still wont work upon first click of tab. basically when i click on the tab view it wont trigger the on appear the first time i click it.

Comment: I have chosen to smash my computer as I cannot figure this out. Goodluck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Add the body in your `ContentView` and remove the `setupInitialListeners()` from two places. Either put it inside the `ConversationsListView` or `ContentView`, and it will work fine as expected. When you tap on `Messages` tab, the `setupInitialListeners()` function will be called when the view appears. Here is my code, which is working fine.

**and Please provide minimal reproducible code next time**

```
import SwiftUI

enum Tab {
    case friends
    case Messages
    case settings
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .friends
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            
            FriendsView(selectedTab: $selectedTab, cameFromConversationsListView: true)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Friends", systemImage: "message")
                }
                .tag(Tab.friends)
            
            ConversationsListView(selectedTab: $selectedTab, cameFromConversationsListView: true)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Messages", systemImage: "person.fill")
                }
                .tag(Tab.Messages)
                .onAppear {
                    setupInitialListeners()
                }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
                }
                .tag(Tab.settings)
        }
    }
    
    func setupInitialListeners() {
        print("setupInitialListeners tapped")
    }
}

struct FriendsView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    var cameFromConversationsListView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Friends View")
    }
}

struct ConversationsListView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    var cameFromConversationsListView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Conversations List View")
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Settings View")
    }
}
```

Comment: That didnt fix the issue and I have already done all that... the listener is being triggered but it just wont trigger the first time I click on the tab after signing in initially.. I have tried so many diff solutions at this point. I really cant figure this out. Sorry for not posting full mpc. I have built the entire app it is jus this last issue I don't know what is causing this. Seems no one else has had a similar situation. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Neo, at my end, it's working fine as expected. 'setupInitialListeners tapped' is printing in the console on the first tap on the Messages tab. It seems like any other click or TapGesture is conflicting in your case. I suggest trying the above code in a separate demo project and checking again to confirm it's not related to your TabView code structure.

Comment: I was also seeing the print statement being shown but it would not actually call the function from the on appear with that approach... seems strange but it genuinely would not I still dont know why. I figured out a working solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work and finally call the listener... strangely enough it only works when I use...

```
       .onDisappear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {setupListeners()}



 } .onAppear { DispatchQueue.main.async { setupListeners() }
}
```

and put the same call for the listener in both functions...when I tried to call it individually in either disappear or appear it wont trigger... But when using both with on disappear above the appear it works. I have no idea why but I played around and tried this and now it does work.. maybe this will help someone in the future. Thanks allot for your responses Jayant. You gave me a reason to keep trying. All the best.